# If image SRC is unknown

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add a class to a image when its src is unknown

This is what I've tried

```
if ($(".main-template img").attr('src') != '') {
    $(this).addClass('noRelImage');
}
```

Also, I tried

```
if ($(".main-template img").src.length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass('noRelImage');
}
```

With no luck

This is how the markup looks:

```
<div class="main-template">
   <img src="">
</div>
```

[image]

I've read a few other posts but none of their answers solved this

Comment: `src(unknown)` isn't valid HTML. Perhaps you mean to use `src="(unknown)"` or `src=""` instead. Then you can use a basic attribute selector in CSS (definitely not JS) to do what you need.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan src(unknown) is not valid, I know. But that's what the system outputs and I can't modify this

Answer (score 2):

Your first condition has the opposite logic and the `$(this)` inside the `if` depends on the context: it should be

```
var img = $(".main-template img");
if (img.attr('src') === "") {
    img.addClass('noRelImage');
}
```

Also note that if you need to add a class only for styling purpose you could avoid using Javascript/jQuery at all and just write an attribute selector in your css declarations, like

```
img[src=""] {
  /* style here */
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do it with just CSS. That solved my query. Thanks!